# Multiline posting in HTML

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm totally new at web development and I am currently trying to create a little website. The goal of this site, is to show random quotes of some of my teachers. The main pages are actually working just fine (I can get random quotes of my whole database, and random quotes from every teacher). But, I wanted to show all the quotes on the same page, and it happens they just appear all on the same line... And it's quite embarrassing...
In my python code, I used "\n" between each quote, so each new one started on a new line. But, on my HTML code, when I pass this string, it seems to have no effect I all the quotes just follow themselves on one line....

I'm using a Flask application, and a python class:

```
for i in range(2, max):
     inte = inte + citation.ClasseCitations('Classe/citations.json','Classe/profs.json', prof, i).corps + ' \n '
     return render_template("integrale.html", citation=inte, auteur=prof)
```

In my HTML file, I use citation like this:

```
<p>{{ citation }}</p>
```

Comment: HTML ignores whitespace, including newlines. You need to use HTML markup, such as `p` and `br` tags.

Comment: Hi thks. I'm ok with using br tags to start a new line when i code the paragraph in the HTML file. But here, the citation argument between {{ }} does not react to anything (i tried \n from python as in my post, and tried to replace it with <\br> but didn't worked either...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
for i in range(2, max):
 inte = inte + citation.ClasseCitations('Classe/citations.json','Classe/profs.json', prof, i).corps + ' <br/> '
 return render_template("integrale.html", citation=inte, auteur=prof)
```

Comment: I tried, but had to add the autoescape, yet it's working :D thanks everyone
{% autoescape false %} {{citation}} {% endautoescape %}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment, but try it with

```
<br/>
```

instead of

```
\n
```

this could work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using a list object within your flask-app.

Then in your html:

```
{% for quote in quotes %}
{{quote}} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

More on jinja2's for-loops
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#for-loop